# Sorting strings with integer values in python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, functional-programming, string-comparison

I have some code that I find clumsy.

Given:

```
sample_lists = [(u'1', u'penguin'), (u'2', u'kelp'), (u'5', u'egg')], 
               [(u'3', u'otter'), (u'4', u'clam')]
```

I want the result: `['penguin', 'kelp', 'otter', 'clam', 'egg']` (ordered by number). You can assume that lists always contains `'1'`, and each sub-list is in ascending order, and that all the numbers in `sample_lists` are consecutive integers, if that helps.

Currently, the most pythonic/concise way I can think of doing this is:

```
sample_list = sample_lists[0]+sample_lists[1]
for i in xrange(len(sample_list)):
    sample_list[0] = i+1
return zip(*sorted(sample_list, key=operator.itemgetter(0)))[1]
```

Is there a better way? I feel like this is quite clumsy. The problem here is sorting by the strings, which I need to convert over to ints one-by-one. A hunch would be some lambda function, but I'm not terribly well versed in that syntax. If this is the best way, I'm still curious as to how to do this using lambda functions, if possible.

Note that the direct string comparison one-liner:

```
print zip(*sorted(sample_lists[0]+sample_lists[1], key=operator.itemgetter(0)))[1]
```

Does not work, as it fails if sample_lists contains '11' or '20'.

**A python 3 answer is okay, but python 2.7 is preferred.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

itemgetter is cool, but doesn't let you convert to int. In this case a lambda function is better as it lets you do the itemgetting and int converting together

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> [x[1] for x in sorted(chain.from_iterable(sample_lists), key=lambda x:int(x[0]))]
[u'penguin', u'kelp', u'otter', u'clam', u'egg']
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using chain.from_iterable as opposed to sample_lists[0]+sample_lists[1]?

Comment: @JDong, what if sample_lists has more than two elements?

Answer (score 1):

[Nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17646772/897968), gnibbler! The only thing that I think is missing is the conversion from the sample_lists to your sample_list, which could be done like so:

`sample_list = [item for lst in sample_lists for item in lst]`

Comment: Yes, I had missed that. You can also use `chain.from_iterable` and do it inside the `sort`

Comment: @gnibbler: True, that would probably be more efficient, but I'm not that familiar with `chain` yet ;-)